# What is the alternative filter for deprecated android.hardware.camera.autofocus?

Tags: android, android-manifest

I know that the filter ***"android.hardware.camera.autofocus"*** is deprecated from `sdk 21`.

I also know that I can check it programmatically when app is running.

But, the question is that isn't there an alternative filter and must I do it programmatically?

If there isn't, can you explain the reason of not doing the work using filters?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I know that the filter "android.hardware.camera.autofocus" is deprecated from sdk 21.

It has not been deprecated, at least according to [the documentation](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/pm/PackageManager.html#FEATURE_CAMERA_AUTOFOCUS) and [the documentation](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/uses-feature-element.html).

> isn't there an alternative filter

You can use `<uses-feature>` for `android.hardware.camera.autofocus`, as it does not appear to be deprecated.

Comment: I see.

But as this doc shows:

https://developer.android.com/reference/android/hardware/Camera.html

the class android.hardware.camera is deprecated in sdk 21.

Android Studio itself automatically recommends using camera2 too.

So i thought there would be an alternative.

Comment: @madisan: "the class android.hardware.camera is deprecated in sdk 21" -- that is a Java class (`android.hardware.Camera`), not a `uses-feature` value. " Android Studio itself automatically recommends using camera2 too" -- there is no `uses-feature` value with `camera2` in it.